# Convert C# linq code to VB. [ Edited ]

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I want to port some of my EntityFramework C# code into VB.NET. I'm trying different online code convertor but they can't solve this problem for me.

I have these two functions.

```
public List<T> Find<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate) where T : class
    {
        var objectSet = db.CreateObjectSet<T>();
        return objectSet.Where<T>(predicate).ToList();
    }

    public void Delete<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate) where T : class
    {
        var objectSet = db.CreateObjectSet<T>();
        IEnumerable<T> records = from x in objectSet.Where<T>(predicate) select x;

        foreach (T record in records)
        {
            objectSet.DeleteObject(record);
        }
    }
```

Now convertors tell me this:

```vb
Public Function Find(Of T As Class)(predicate As Func(Of T, Boolean)) As List(Of T)
    Dim objectSet = db.CreateObjectSet(Of T)()
    Return objectSet.Where(Of T)(predicate).ToList()
End Function

Public Sub Delete(Of T As Class)(predicate As Func(Of T, Boolean))
    Dim objectSet = db.CreateObjectSet(Of T)()
    Dim records As IEnumerable(Of T) = From x In objectSet.Where(Of T)(predicate) Select x

    For Each record As T In records
        objectSet.DeleteObject(record)
    Next
End Sub
```

But I get two errors, both for `objectSet.Where<T>(predicate)` which is:

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Where' accepts this number of type arguments.

Comment: You posted the same code twice.

Comment: Can you include your vb.net code?

Comment: now it has noth VB.NET and C# code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply remove the type argument from your call to `Where`, it’s unnecessary anyway. Secondly, decide on a style: either use LINQ or functions, not both.

That is,

- either write:

  ```vb
  Dim records As IEnumerable(Of T) = From x In objectSet Where predicate(x) Select x
  ```

  … but in VB you can leave off the `Select x`:

  ```vb
  Dim records As IEnumerable(Of T) = From x In objectSet Where predicate(x)
  ```
- or write:

  ```vb
  Dim records As IEnumerable(Of T) = objectSet.Where(predicate)
  ```

Same for `Find`. Simply write:

```vb
Return objectSet.Where(predicate).ToList()
```